# Derivation of Liénard-Wiechert Potential in quasi-rest reference frame

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lienard-wiechert

In electrodynamics, using the Maxwell equation:
$\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=\frac{4\pi}{c}J^{\nu}$, together with the Lorentz gauge: $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}=0$, we can derive the equation for vector potential:$\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}A^{\nu}=\frac{4\pi}{c}J^{\nu}$.

With this equation, we can use the retarded Green's function to derive the Liénard-Wiechert Potential:
$$A^{\mu}(x)=\left.\frac{e u^{\mu}(\tau)}{u \cdot[x-r(\tau)]}\right|_{\tau=\tau_{0}}$$
where $u^{\mu}(\tau)=\frac{dr^{\mu}(\tau)}{d\tau}$ and $\tau_0$ is the retarded time satisfying the light-cone condition: $(x-r(\tau_0))^2=0$.

However, there's another derivation of the Liénard-Wiechert Potential which makes use of the quasi-rest reference frame of the charged particle. It states that in the reference frame which moves with the same velocity as the charged particle at a particular moment (still an inertial frame of reference), the vector potential can be regarded as Coulomb potential, and we can derive the Liénard-Wiechert Potential by simply performing a Lorentz transformation.

What confuses me in this derivation is that, how to justify that acceleration of the particle does not contribute to the vector potential? Namely, in the quasi-rest frame, the particle may still have nonzero acceleration, so why is the potential still Coulomb potential?

Meanwhile, although the derivation of the Liénard-Wiechert Potential by performing a Lorentz transformation yields the correct result, we can not get the correct field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ by assuming the electric field in the quasi-rest frame is Coulomb-like and perform a transformation. It's clear that we can't involve the acceleration of the particle in this way, which contradicts the fact that the electric and magnetic field depend on the acceleration of the particle.

So my question is, is it coincidence that we can get the correct vector potential but not the correct E-M field by using the quasi-rest frame and performing a Lorentz transformation, or there's some reason hiding behind this result?